# asp.net detailsview iteminsert event

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have a Detailsview connected to a database table using EntityDataSource. It has a table called Employee that has a field EMPID as a primary key. I want to randomly generate value for this field. How would I be able to insert other fields value from the detailsview and EMPID from the code behind through ITEMINSERTING event.

My situation is: I have a table named

```
Employee(EmpId, Name, DOB, Gender, DeptId, Position).
```

Employees are added to the dbase by entering all the info manually but i want to generate EmpId automatically, so EmpId field is hidded to user. With `detailsview` (on base of my knowledge) using Enable Insert, I could insert data to dbase but i am having difficult on how to insert the auto generated EmpId on `Detailsview_ItemInserting` event. I have not written any code on C#.

Thank you!!!

Comment: share your code so that people can understand your question better!

Comment: My situation is:
I have a table named Employee(EmpId, Name, DOB, Gender, DeptId, Position). Employees are added to the dbase by entering all the info manually but i want to generate EmpId automatically, so EmpId field is hidded to user. With detailsview(on base of my knowledge) using Enable Insert, I could insert data  to dbase but i am having difficult on how to insert the auto generated EmpId on Detailsview_ItemInserting event. 
I have not written any code on C#.

Comment: Is your `EmpId` database field currently auto generated in the database??? Something like an `Identity` field or with `newid()`?

Comment: EmpId is not enabled to auto generate. I am using GUID to generate random identity.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you all for your considerations!!!

Comment: would you like to share your solution?